# Testing & pallet_collective

Tags: testing, pallet-collective

I have a pallet that is using the pallet_collective to trigger votes for roles affectations requests. everything works fine in the polkadot.js interface, but testing is not going as expected.

in the mock file, I have the following for `construct_runtime!`:

```rs
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test 
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config<T>, Storage, Event<T>},
        RolesModule: pallet_roles::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},
        Sudo:pallet_sudo::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},
        Collective: pallet_collective::<Instance2>::{Pallet, Call, Event<T>, Origin<T>, Config<T>},
    }
)
```

The function that is supposed to start the referendum is the following:

```rs
pub fn start_council_session(account: T::AccountId,account_type: Accounts) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo{
    //Create proposal
    let proposal0 = 
        Call::<T>::account_approval{
            account: account.clone()
        };
    let proposal = Self::get_formatted_call(proposal0.into()).unwrap();

    
                    
    let proposal_len:u32 = proposal.using_encoded(|p| p.len() as u32);
    
    let council_member = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::members()[0].clone();
    let council_origin= Self::get_origin(council_member);

    //Start Collective refererendum
    Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::propose(
        council_origin,
        2,
        Box::new(proposal.clone()),
        proposal_len,
    ).ok();
    let mut index:u32 = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposal_count();
    index = index.saturating_sub(1);

    //Update proposal index and hash
    let proposal_hashes =  Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposals().into_iter();
    for proposal_hash in proposal_hashes{
        let prop0 = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposal_of(proposal_hash.clone()).unwrap();
        if proposal == prop0{
            let mut proposal_all = Proposal::<T>::new(account.clone(), Some(account_type),proposal_hash.clone());
            proposal_all.proposal_index = index;
            proposal_all.proposal_hash = proposal_hash;
            RequestedRoles::<T>::insert(&account, proposal_all);
        }
        
    }

    
    Ok(().into())
}
```

Calling the extrinsic that is using this function does not generate any error, but If I try the following `assert_eq!(Collective::proposal_count(),1);` or the following: `assert_eq!(Collective::proposals().len(),1);` both tests fail saying that I still have 0 proposal. why would an extrinsic would work "manually" but not in the tests?

**Edit 1**

Adding the rest of the test to show where it's failing=> the exact same workflow executed in Polkadot.js works perfectly. the `start_council_session` function  mentionned above is within the `set_roles` extrinsic, and should be triggered for the `SELLER` role. unfortunately things don't go as expected...:

```
#[test]
fn setting_roles(){
new_test_ext().execute_with(||{
    assert_eq!(RolesModule::get_pending_servicers().len(), 0);
    assert_eq!(RolesModule::get_pending_house_sellers().len(), 0);
    assert_eq!(RolesModule::get_pending_notaries().len(), 0);
    let council = Collective::members();
    assert_eq!(council.len(),3);


    //Investor & Tenant roles
    assert_ok!(RolesModule::set_role(RuntimeOrigin::signed(DAVE), DAVE, Acc::INVESTOR));
    assert_ok!(RolesModule::set_role(RuntimeOrigin::signed(EVE), EVE, Acc::TENANT));
    assert!(InvestorLog::<Test>::contains_key(DAVE));
    assert!(TenantLog::<Test>::contains_key(EVE));

    //Seller,Servicer, and Notary roles
    assert_ok!(RolesModule::set_role(RuntimeOrigin::signed(BOB),BOB,Acc::SELLER));
    assert_eq!(RolesModule::get_pending_house_sellers().len(),1);
    let account =RolesModule::get_pending_house_sellers()[0].account_id.clone();
    assert_eq!(account,BOB);

    
    //Check that collective referendum started --> test failing at the first assertion below
    assert_eq!(Collective::proposal_count(),1); 
    assert_eq!(Collective::proposals().len(),1);
    

    assert_ok!(RolesModule::council_vote(RuntimeOrigin::signed(council[0].clone()),BOB,true));              
})
}
```

Comment: I can't see where the assertion is located.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier , I editted the post, and added some details

Comment: Still need more detail. Was `start_council_session` called from `on_initialize`?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier, not from `on_initialize`, but from the extrinsic `set_role`. You can see it on line 439: https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/blob/optimize_9.40/pallets/roles/src/lib.rs